# discord.py how to make a command has permissons

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and have made a piece of code that mutes everybody in a voice channel. I want to make sure that only a Mod or someone with Administrator permissions can use this command.

Here is my code for my mute command:

```py
@client.command()
async def vcmute(ctx):
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in vc.members:
        await member.edit(mute=True)
    await ctx.send('Mics are closed!')
```

And this is my unmute command (Which would use the same concept of only Administrator or Mod using it):

```py
@client.command()
async def vcunmute(ctx):
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in vc.members:
        await member.edit(mute=False)
    await ctx.send('Mics are opened!')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get permissions for the sender in his current channel you can use
`perms = ctx.author.permissions_in(ctx.author.voice.channel)`. Then you can check if that user has muting permissions with

```
if perms.mute_members:
    #whatever you want your command to do
else:
    #no permission error msg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `has_permissions` decorator

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) # Or whatever perms you want
async def vcmute(ctx):
    ...


# If you wanna send some message if the user doesn't have the needed permissions
@vcmute.error
async def vcmute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"You need {error.missing_perms} permissions to use this command.")
```

Comment: Thanks but, is this for a specific role or something? Well if it is then i don't want something like that sorry.

Comment: It's called `has_permissions` why would it be for roles? For roles is `commands.has_role`.

Comment: i guess i misunderstood there sorry but that's not the point, the point is that when i do what you said i always get this error: ```@commands.has_permissions(admin=True)
  File "C:\Users\muham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1758, in has_permissions
    raise TypeError('Invalid permission(s): %s' % (', '.join(invalid)))
TypeError: Invalid permission(s): admin```

Comment: cause it is „administrator” not „admin”

Comment: btw i am trying to add `mute _members` too but when i add that code it just verifies administrator but not mute members, well the point is, i have mute members perm but still i cant mute anyone with this `vcmute` command

Comment: That's weird, did you put it in the same decorator? Also, do you have `intents.members`enabled?

Comment: yeah i puted in the same decorator but how am i supposed to enable `intents.members`?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents

Comment: i enabled Privileged Gateway Intents by developer portal and by code but it still wont work pls help

Comment: no errors just the `mute_members` perm is not verified. My bot always says, 'you should have mute_members perm to use this command' when i try to use `vcmute` command